# Is there any way I can make CXF ignore namespaces?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

When calling a method of a service, using CXF classes generated from WSDL, I get error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.some.com/vxs", local:"Extended"). Expected elements are <{http://www.some.com/vxs}Material>,<{http://www.some.com/vxs},<{http://www.some.com/vxs}Duration>...
```

So, WSDL contains declaration with namespace, but service provides response without it.
Is there a way to get response despite missing namespaces?

Tried this, didn't work, still same error: [cxf Unmarshalling Error : unexpected element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164987/cxf-unmarshalling-error-unexpected-element)

Also tried, same error:

```
((BindingProvider) conversionService.getConversionServicePort()).getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled", "false");
```

My code doesn't use any additional configuration, only default:

```
public static ConversionService buildConversionService() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL wsdlUrl = new URL("https://my-site.com/ConversionService?wsdl");
    ConversionService_Service conversionService_service = new ConversionService_Service(wsdlUrl);

    return conversionService_service.getConversionServicePort();
}
```

Client generated with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources4</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/wsdl/ConversionService.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please show the current configuration/code of your client.

Comment: @slindenau it's default configuration all the way